# how do i make the image in a table fit inside the cell and not overflow or expand the cells using html and css

Tags: html, css, cell

I have a table of fixed sizer with images inside a div in each cells.
The image should be scaled down proportionally to the size of the table cell..
but when i show image, it is overflowing with the height expanding the cell and table itslef. but the width is scaled to fit inside the cell

here is the code (.cells is the div inside the td and the table is inside a fixed length div container

```
.view-grid {
  height: 565px;
  width: 1000px;
}
table {
  height: 565px;
  width: 1000px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}
.cells {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

making the div’s or td’s fixed is not an options since the table can be 2x2 or 3x2 or 4x4 based on user selection. The above code will fit the image widthwise in any dimension. But height overflows.

Update: ***Worked!***

```
overflow: auto;
```

inside the .cells worked (.cells is the div inside the td)

Comment: Can you share your table html code

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please include your `HTML` as well. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i'm using react. however i'll share the view from debugg console

Comment: Use `max-width` and `max-height` for image.

Comment: adding max-width and max-height  100%will expand the cell to the table size when image is added

Comment: max-width and max-height set in px value

Comment: since the table and its container everything is 100%, image will take the as much as width and height of its actual size.
Try to set the height and width for the image or .cells

Comment: i cannot make the td fixed. since the table dimension varies based on user selection. 2 x 2 or 3 x 3 or 4 x 4

Comment: Can you try `img { object-fit: cover; }` instead of the current `img` styles?

Comment: Thanks but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Without seeing this live the fix is too elusive. Please add it here and provide a link: codesandbox.io/

Comment: Sorry, But this is react code. And i cannot share the full repo

Comment: i changed the code for table as follows. It fixed the width issue. For 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 tables, the image width is fitting perfectly inside the cells. But height is overflowing. Any idea what could be the problem? –

Comment: table { height: 565px; width: 1000px; } tbody{ } td { border: solid 1px; height: calc(100% / 4); width: calc(100% / 4); } .cells { height: 100%; width: 100%; } img { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

Comment: Thank you all. It finally worked with the solution I updated in original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `table` have two `td` in `tr` so you can use below css

```
.view-grid table img
{
    max-width:50vw;
}
```

Comment: but unfortunatly. the number of td is not fixed. Like i mentioned, the table can be 2D or 3D or 4D

Comment: Than you have to use `jquery` for that. Count td in tr and divide 100vw/number-of-td.

Comment: since this is react. I was hoping for a solution without passing a value to css

Comment: i changed the code for table as follows. It fixed the width issue. For 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 tables, the image width is fitting perfectly inside the cells. But height is overflowing. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: table {
  height: 565px;
  width: 1000px;
}
tbody{
}
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  width: calc(100% / 4);
}
.cells {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Select the image and try object-fit: cover

Comment: Sorry this didn't prevent overflow.